# Difference between Promoter and Benefactor badges?

Tags: support, badges, bounty-badges

Benefactor = First bounty you manually awarded on your own question.
Promoter = First bounty you offered on your own question.

What is the difference?  Sometimes I think that the explanation of the badges are not so clear...

Comment: I've created a master list of all the badges at [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions); if you don't think it's clear enough, you can edit it yourself (once you get 100 rep).

Comment: Basically you copied and pasted the default description. Some of them you detailed more.. but "Promoter" and "Benefactor" are exactly the same...

Comment: I know. Since you don't find Promoter/Benefactor to be clear, I'm inviting you to fix it yourself once you get the rep. (I'm actually in the middle of trying to make it better right now, but since I'm not the one who's confused, I don't really know if I've done a good job of making it not-confusing.)

Comment: @Popular Demand: Sure you did..thanks for that. I'll surely help on that. Thanks again.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Promoter = You **started** a bounty
Benefactor = You (manually) **awarded** a bounty, i.e. you really gave the rep to someone

Answer (score 7):

You can start a bounty but let the system auto assign it, so in that case you'd get only the Promoter one.

Instead, if you manually award it, you'd get both.

EDIT: As Tobias pointed out, you can get the Benefactor for a second question if you didn't award it in the first.

Comment: since these badges are one-time only, after your mentioned case Benefactor could be awarded for another question at some later point